# How to use pattern matching inside a function?

Tags: haskell

I'm struggling with implementation of an unbounded knapsack problem solver. I want to use recursion and memoization instead of explicit state.

But the problem is that I can't find a way to express my thoughts in valid Haskell. Both versions This gives me

```
    parse error on input ‘=’
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'



bestUnbounded :: [Integer] -> Integer -> ([Integer], Integer)
bestUnbounded items capacity = if capacity <= 0
                                  then ([], 0)
                                  else maximumBy (comparing snd) solutions
                                      where solutions = filter (\ s -> snd s <= capacity) $ map solve items
                                            solve i   = (solution, weight + i)
                                                where solution, weight = bestUnbounded items (capacity - i)




bestUnbounded :: [Integer] -> Integer -> ([Integer], Integer)
bestUnbounded items capacity
  | capacity <= 0 = ([], 0)
  | otherwise     = maximumBy (comparing snd) solutions
      where solutions = filter (\ s -> snd s <= capacity)  map solve items
            solve i   = let solution, weight = bestUnbounded items (capacity - i)
                        in (solution, weight + i)
```

If anyone could also show how to use `Data.Func.Memoize` on that I would be also grateful.

EDIT1

Working solution

```
import Data.List (maximumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.Function.Memoize (memoize)

bestUnbounded :: [Integer] -> Integer -> ([Integer], Integer)
bestUnbounded items capacity
  | capacity <= 0 = ([], 0)
  | otherwise     = solver' capacity
  where solver' = memoize solver
        solver capacity = maximumBy (comparing snd) solutions
        solutions = filter (\ s -> snd s <= capacity) $ map solve items
        solve i   = let (solution, weight) = bestUnbounded items (capacity - i)
                    in (i : solution, weight + i)
```

Comment: A parse error means the compiler couldn't even make sense of your code. You didn't include the part reference in the error message so I'm not sure we can help you with it (but perhaps you need a `let` in a `do` block?). You've got other syntax errors as well that I can see at a quick glance

Comment: @jberryman `Knapsack.hs:10:72: error:` I didn't included it because you don't know the line numbers. Well, if you see syntax errors and you understand what I meant, can you show how to write that in Haskell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't syntactically valid:

```
solution, weight = bestUnbounded items (capacity - i)
```

I think you meant to pattern match on `(,)` like this:

```
(solution, weight) = bestUnbounded items (capacity - i)
```

The tuple syntax always requires parentheses, for both construction and pattern matching.

Comment: Thanks! I'm used to python tuple unpacking, so I missed that. Can you also show how to memoize this? I tried `bestUnbounded [1..100] 10000` and got hanging and stack overflow error.